# How to get the correct ID after saving a Hibernate object?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, insert

I'm using Hibernate and Oracle. I want to save an object and get its ID, which is generated by a trigger that uses a sequence. (The use of a trigger is a requirement.) There are two ways to get the ID currently at my disposal: 1) find the maximum value of the ID column; 2) find the current value of the sequence. Both methods suffer the same problem, namely that another insert may happen between saving this object and getting the ID. **How can I avoid such untimely inserts?**

Additionally, these two events happen in a transaction that doesn't end after getting the ID. In other words there will be things happening afterwards. So if I lock the table, the lock won't be released until the transaction is over. This is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the sequence id [generation strategy](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html) for you entity, you should overcome this problem as:

**1)** You can specify `allocationSize` which would allocate certain number of Ids up-front for you and be available for you within a certain transaction.

**2)** Once you call `session.save(entity)` or `entityManager.persist(entity)`, the Id will be available to you straight away after the call, without the need to wait till the end of the transactional method and the actual `flush` and `commit`.